# Publishing PDFs when using Tridion Razor templates

Tags: razor, tridion, razor-mediator

I am having a problem publishing binaries (PDF files) from Tridion using Razor Templating.

I have a Component Template that is set to 'Published as a Dynamic Component' with a single linked Multimedia Schema.

I am using the [Razor Mediator eXtension](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/razormediator.aspx) and the Component Template contains two Template Building Blocks:

1. A Razor Template that output some HTML and the link to the binary in the Multimedia Component.
2. The Default Finish Actions TBB containing the following:

   - Publish Binaries in Package
   - Link Resolver
   - Target Group Personalization
   - Cleanup Template
   - Convert Xml to Html

The Razor Template contains the following code (I have simplified this slightly):
[image]

This appears to be resolving the binary link correctly and produces the following Dynamic Component Presentation:
[image]

The problem that I am having is that the binary itself is never added to the package and so does not get published.

As the Razor Mediator has an 'extractBinaries' setting in the Tridion.ContentManager.config file then I suspect that the binaries should be added on to the package by the mediator.  I have made sure that the extractBinaries setting is set to 'true', however the binary is not being added to the package (although the Multimedia Component being processed is on the package as a tridion/component item).

Does anyone know if this functionality is available and working in the Razor Mediator please?  I suspect that Razor Mediator is expecting the link code to be in a specific format, but I cannot find anything on this in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/downloads/detail?name=RazorMediatorDocumentation_v1.2.docx&can=2&q=).

I have also tried adding the 'Extract Binaries from Html' TBB to the Component Template (following the Razor Template) but I get the following error:
*"The item Output must have property TCMURI specified"*.
I suspect that this is due to the way that the Razor Mediator is adding the 'Output' item to the package.

I could write a new TBB to make sure that the binary is added to the package, but I would prefer to avoid doing this if the functionality is already available with the Razor Mediator.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  Apologies for the images.  Stackoverflow didn't want to format the code correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: SLacks - As your link says, I think that the problem was that "Markdown and HTML is ignored within a code block".  Thanks, Jon

Comment: Are you sure that having a <a href to a binary is actually supposed to publish that binary? Most Tridion modules typically only auto-publish binaries that are required to show the published content correctly, so things like <img src=. Binaries that are linked are often intentionally treated differently - although I can't speak for whether the Razor Mediator is supposed to publish linked binaries automatically.

Comment: Hi Frank.  Yes, I agree that you would normally have to enable the publishing of the binaries from within your templates.  However, as the Razor Mediator has an 'extractBinaries' setting I suspect that this should be able to handle it.  Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the Razor Mediator currently doesn't add the PDF binary to the package when in an  tag (thus not getting picked up by the Publish Binaries TBB), though I have a pretty good feeling that version 1.3 will be taking care of this ;).

In the meantime, you can use a "Add Unresolved Binary Dependencies" type of TBB.  I don't have it on hand at the moment, but let me know if you need it and I'll post the code for you later tonight.

**EDIT**
Cancel my statement about it not getting added to package, I was thinking of a different scenario.

Try the following instead:

```
<a href="@Component.ID">@Component.Metadata.title</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I thought that the functionality would be in there - I just didn't know the syntax.  I will give it a try as soon as I'm back in the office and post an update.

Comment: Hi Alex.  Many thanks for your response on this.  I have tested it and it appears that using the syntax that you suggest does add the PDF Component to the Package and publish it.  This does however raise another problem in that it does not append the tcmId of the Component to the file name.  Meaning that there are errors if two PDFs (contained in different Folder in Tridion) with the same file name are published then there are publish failures.  As my site has thousands of PDFs, I suspect that I may have to use a separate TBB for this.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@{ 
  var item = TridionHelper.Package.CreateMultimediaItem(Component.ID);
  TridionHelper.Package.PushItem("CurrentMultimedia", item);
}
```

Followed, of course by PublishBinariesInPackage, although as you can also reach the Engine in a similar way, perhaps a direct AddBinary would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the Razor Mediator, but have you tried adding the `Default Finish Actions` or the `Publish Binaries in Package` TBBs to your template?

Comment: Hi Chris.  The Component Template already contains 'Default Finish Actions' TBB (which contains the 'Publish Binaries in Package' TBB).  The problem is that the binary is never on the package to be published.  Thanks, Jon